# How to be sure a bytecode is conform to a source code

Tags: solidity, compilation

Let's suppose a company shows me a contract's code source.
This code source has been audited and looks fine.
I trust this source code and i want to send Ether to this contract.

The company tells me the contract has been deployed to an Ethereum Address. How can i be sure the deployed contract is exactly the same than the code source ?

In fact i want to be sure the source code we show me is exactly the same than the deployed one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Online blockchain browsers have exactly the same functionality - for example Etherscan has a concept of a "verified contract". A verified contract is one for which the source code is verified to be the one shown in their site.

To verify a contract in Etherscan you basically have to give them the source code with various parameters, Etherscan compiles it and compares the produced bytecode. If the bytecodes match, it gets verified. So, in theory, the process is rather straightforward but in reality there are quite many parameters to think of so it's sometimes a bit complicated.